# How can I make an SSIS Conditional Split task fail the process if rows are sent to default output

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, conditional-split

I have a Conditional Split task in my workflow which directs the data to one of three different destinations.

*All* my data should go to one of these three destinations. If there is data that does not conform to this rule it should cause the process to fail *(i.e. nothing gets Loaded and the user is given an error)*.

Is there any way in SSIS to cause a Conditional Split task to fail the process if data is sent to its default output?

Comment: You could use a Custom data flow component as a destination of the default output and raise an error if any rows are passed in.

Comment: Are you interested in what this bad data is? You could load it into a logging table and fail if any records appear there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way to do that is to add a Script Component *(Destination)* after the Default Output. And Throw an exception from the Script Component. As example *(VB.NET)*

```
Throw new Exception("Condition are not met!")
```

- [Creating and Throwing Exceptions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions)

Comment: @MikeM i fixed it :)

Comment: :-)  I see.  Happy Monday!